# How to sort entities by 5 star user rating

Tags: math

I am trying to find a formula

http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

The one from the above link is too hard to implement.
Is there a nicer and simpler way to sort entities by a five star user rating control ?

Think at jokes. People say jokes and others rate them with 1 to 5 stars.
If 
a) 5 users rate a joke with 5, 
b) another 1000 rate another joke with 4 and finally, 
c) another 1000 rate another joke with 3.8, 
I want this specific order:

- joke b)
- joke c)
- joke a)

Comment: There is not enough info to answer your question.  What if 10,000 votes for a joke all rate it 1?

Comment: This is a relevant question. It's a basic question how to handle star ratings items with  different voting amounts. The lack of data of 10K rating it 1 is not necessary to understand the OP essential question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a Bayesian Rating system and it's quite simple:

http://www.thebroth.com/blog/118/bayesian-rating

Comment: every time someone vote\rate, those magic numbers must be updates in some table. i am right ? is this what you do ?

Comment: There's a number of ways to go about it.  For large systems with lots of votes I've done scheduled jobs that updates a database.  For small systems I just calc it on the fly.